# "cout" and "char address"

Tags: c++, char, cout

```
char p;
cout << &p;
```

This does not print the address of character p. It prints some characters. Why?

```
char p;
char *q;
q = &p;
cout << q;
```

Even this does not. Why?

Comment: `&p` equates to a `char*`, and the `<<` operator has a special overload to treat `char*` as a null-terminated C-string.

Comment: printf is much more elegant here. `printf("%p\n", (void *)pointer);`

Answer (score 14):

I believe the `<<` operator recognizes it as a string. Casting it to a `void*` *should* work:

```
cout << (void*)&p;
```

`std::basic_ostream` has a specialized operator that takes a `std::basic_streambuf` (which basically *is* a string (in this case)):

```
_Myt& operator<<(_Mysb *_Strbuf)
```

as opposed to the operator that takes any pointer (except `char*` of course):

```
_Myt& operator<<(const void *_Val)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because the pointer to `char` has its own overload of `<<`, which *interprets* the pointer as a C string.

You can fix your code by adding a cast to `void*`, which is the overload that prints a pointer:

```
char p;
cout << (void*)&p << endl;
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/YUzAw6)

Note that the problem happens for `char` pointer, but not for other kinds of pointers. Say, if you use `int` instead of `char` in your declaration, your code would work without a cast:

```
int p;
cout << &p << endl;
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/Eg1Hui)

Answer (score 3):

`std::cout` will treat a `char*` as a string. You are basically seeing whatever is contained in memory at the location of your uninitialised pointer - until a terminating null character is encountered. Casting the pointer to a void* should print the actual pointer value if you need to see it