# Is std::cout of a char reference defined by the standard?

Tags: c++, reference, char, ascii, memory-address

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188668/cout-and-char-address) and the answers indicate a behavior described in a paragraph below.  I am not trying to make it work on my machine, or find a workaround to make it work on my machine, it is a question of is it defined behavior according to the standard.

Consider the following code which creates an int variable, an int-reference variable, and prints out the result of calling the address-operator on the int-reference variable

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a = 70;
    int& b = a;

    std::cout << &b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out what I would expect, which is an address in memory, i.e., the address of int variable a.

But now I change int to char, or unsigned char, or signed char, and both on Xcode (Version 6.4) and Visual Studio (VS 2013 Ultimate) I get unexpected behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // or unsigned char or signed char, same weird behavior    
    char a = 70; 
    char& b = a; 

    std::cout << &b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In Xcode, the console prints something like F\330\367\277_\377 .  I get that F is the ASCII code for 70, but I do not understand the rest of it.  I assume it is also a set of ASCII characters, since on Visual Studio it prints out the F followed by some weird characters.

I tried other integer types and it worked fine.  And I know that often char/signed char/unsigned char or some combination of them are implemented as the same type.  The only thing I can think of is that the reference type is being implemented as a pointer type and then interpreting the call to &b as returning a pointer type, and then std::cout is taking its input to mean to print out all characters in a char array.

Is this defined behavior?

To reiterate: my question is more specifically, is this a defined behavior which is part of the standard, is this behavior not defined by the standard, is this a non-standard implementation of the compilers?  Something else?

Comment: The address of `char` results in `char*` which is the type used for "strings" therefore it is printed as a string of characters but it isn't properly null terminated. Does `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&b) << std::endl;` work for you?

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I was asking whether or not this was defined behavior according to the Standard.

Comment: Reading beyond the end of an array results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, I decided to look for myself and found the quote on page 112 of N4431: "The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand."  I understand this is what James was saying but I was looking for a concrete statement in the Standard.  So then taking the address of char is defined behavior, but using it with std::cout yields undefined behavior for the reason James mentioned.  I couldn't find a quote in the Standard for the last part even though I know it is true.