# Meaning of output

Tags: c++, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* cptr{new char};
    std::cout << cptr;
    delete cptr;
}
```

Output:

```
debug.
```

Why? I was expecting an address.

Comment: looks like part of your code is missing. show the full code

Comment: @Ralidex That is the full code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["cout" and "char address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188668/cout-and-char-address)

Comment: C++ iostreams have distinct overloads for printing a `const char *` (which assumes the pointer points at the first character of a nul-terminated string, and prints all characters in that string) and `void *` (which prints the address).   Your code is using the first overload since `cptr` has type `char *`.   Your code ALSO has undefined behaviour since `cptr` does not actually point at (the first character of) a nul terminated string, but your code does stream output in a manner that ASSUMES it does.