# Value pointed by array-name in 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[][6] = { "hello", "hii" };
    cout << a << ", " << *a << ", " << **a;
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : 0x7ffd1f44a20c, hello, h

Now, as we know that the array-name(in this case 'a') in case of 2D array points to the 1D array (in this case "hello"), *a will point to the element in **that (1D array pointed by a)** array and **a will give use the value pointed by *a.
Now in this case i am little confused because of two reasoning:

1. *The output is right*, since the value pointed by 'a' is "hello", and *a will print the value pointed by 'a'.
2. *The output is wrong*, since *a itself is pointing the element inside 1D array and hence *a should have printed the address corresponding to the first element of 1D array pointed by a and the output should have been :

Expected output : 0x7ffd1f44a20c, **address of h**, h

Thank you very much for patience!

Comment: cout operates differently when passed a char* Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188668/cout-and-char-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188668/cout-and-char-address)

Comment: please don't put images in future posts - just write everything in text ...

Comment: @ OrenIshShalom, just wanted to make sure that people understand my doubt!

Answer (score 2):

`a` is only a "2D array" in a limited sense. This is part of the somewhat-weird and not-super-consistent array semantics C++ inherits from C, like [array-to-pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1593077).

So, when you define `a`, what gets placed in memory is: h, e, l, l, o, \0, h, i, i, \0, \0, \0 - in sequence.

- When  you type `a[x][y]`, that's the x*6 + y'th character in that sequence (type `char`);
- When you type `a[x]`, that decays into a `char*` pointing to the x*6'th character in the sequence.
- When you type `a`, that decays into a pointer to 6-element arrays, pointing to a 6-element array starting at the 0'th position in the sequence.

[See this also on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/46YbMPMTz) (using the [type_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56600402/1593077) facility).

Comment: then like what is datatype of `a`, i am actually confused that what is `a`?

Comment: @trev : See the link. The confusing thing is that there's a "decay" from the datatype into something else, so that if you pass it, say, to a function - it gets the "decayed" type; but for template instantiation purposes, the non-decayed type is used.

Comment: @ einpoklum, actually i am fairly beginner in programming, can you explain "decay" in simple language so that i can build concept on top of it?

Comment: @trev: Follow the link I gave about array decay, that's a question explanation. You might also want the C language FAQ about arrays, [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).